# How do I embed a simple HTML Element with a bit of JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress

Here's my problem. I am working with WordPress at the moment and apparently for Security reasons it doesn't allow the script tag. So I uploaded it on a seperate server. Now my question is, whether it is possible to just show the content of that link as a small widget on the Wordpress page, or if I got a big mistake in one or another basic question?

Or to put it in other words, what do I have to do, so that this script is embeddable. A Google Search always resulted in an explanation on how to embed content, but not how to deliver content.

Here is the code:

```
<html>
<center>
<h3>
<p id="demo"></p>
</h3>
</center>
<script>
var countDownDate = new Date("Dec 13, 2018 00:00:00").getTime();
var x = setInterval(function() {
var now = new Date().getTime();
var distance = countDownDate - now;
if (distance >= 0){
  // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
  var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
  var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

  // Display the result in the element with id="demo"
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h "
  + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s " ;}

  // If the count down is finished, write some text 
  if (distance < 0) {
distance = Math.abs(distance);
var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
  var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

  // Display the result in the element with id="demo"
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h "
  + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s " ;

  }
}, 1000);
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: you would point an <iframe> from your WP site to the other server's page where your code lives

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but apparently iframe is not allowed either... :/

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress definitely allows the script tag. You'll add a line like this to your functions.php file to properly add the script to your Wordpress site:

```
wp_enqueue_script ( 'custom-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/custom-script.js' );
```

Comment: Yes, that is true, but I can't access the functions.php file. What I have found out, is that in wordpress.org you can modify the file. But I set up my page on wordpress.com, which makes this option for me unsusable

Comment: Oh, okay. I think you should still be able to wrap your script in a custom plugin and upload that plugin to your wordpress.com site, under the plugins tab?

Comment: Yes, but then I could use a plug in in general. The thing is, I was hoping for a non plugin option, because using plugins would mean, that I need to subscribe for a tariff... And that's not worth it for one script like that

Comment: Ah, I see. According to https://en.support.wordpress.com/code/, adding custom Javascript is only possible for users of the Business or Premium plans. So you don't have many options here unless you pay for Premium or host Wordpress yourself.

Answer (score 0):

WordPress blocks JS in most in user-supplied content but you can still use JS as part of the theme in template files, as well as load your own custom files in the WordPress config, as below:

https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/including-css-javascript/

> Any additional JavaScript files required by a theme should be loaded using wp_enqueue_script. This ensures proper loading and caching, and allows the use conditional tags to target specific pages. These are optional.

Comment: Thank you, but I can not access a functions.php file, since I am using wordpress.com and not .org. Apparentliy there is a difference.